# Can Xcode programactically disabled archive?

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

When my developing App needs to use some testing data, I used to set a variable `testing = true`, and this will popup an alert view warning me in test mode.

I'm looking for a trick in case forget to set it to `false` before archive. Can any code disabled Xcode archive? or if any other can do the similar action?

Comment: You can have different code between debug builds and release builds. No need to worry about forgetting anything. Do some searching on the topic.

Comment: @maddy It's a great suggestion to add a debug flag, I didn't know this before searching. Thanks. Would you like to make it an answer so that I can accept it?